# Как экранировать Json формат?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, json, экранирование

Почему результат данного кода "false"?

```
String myText = "\"assignee\":\"[а-яА-Яa-z_A-z0-9]+$\"";
String myRegex = "\"assignee\":\"[а-яА-Яa-z_A-z0-9]+$\"";
Pattern SREQUESTBODY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(myRegex);
SREQUESTBODY_PATTERN.matcher(myText);
System.out.println(SREQUESTBODY_PATTERN.matcher(myText).find());
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Просто в строке `myText` нет подстроки соответствующей регулярному выражению `myRegex`. Согласно ему после третьей кавычки должны быть буквы, цифры или подчёркивания, а там квадратная скобка.

Comment: После третей кавычки вроде ":" ???

Comment: @HSdevelop, я имею в виду те кавычки, которые в значении переменной, а не в тексте программы. Т.е. первая и последняя не считаются.